# How to create unit test for methods without return statement in Pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to do a pytest on a function without return values in a class:

```
# app.py
from utils import DBConnection


class App:
  def add_ticket_watcher(self, ticket_key, watcher_name):
    if ticket_key is None:
      raise ValueError('Ticket key is empty')

    instance = DBConnection()
    instance.save(ticket_key, watcher_name)
```

From above code, `add_ticket_watcher()` is a method which has no return statement. I learned from this [article](https://coderbook.com/@marcus/how-to-unit-test-functions-without-return-statements-in-python/) that we can use mocks to mimic the expected behavior of this method.

For mocking function with pytest, I found that we can use [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html).

So, my approach is to perform 2 test cases for `add_ticket_watcher()`:

- test valid ticket key
- test invalid ticket key

I have something like:

```
# test_app.py
import pytest
from src.app import App


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = App()
    return app


# Positive test case: Setup parameterize test for valid ticket key
add_valid_watcher_data = (
    ('func_name', 'ticket_key', 'watcher_name', 'expected_result', 'comment'),
    [
        ('add_ticket_watcher', 'TIC-13527', 'someone', None, 'add watcher at valid ticket key'),
    ]
)


@pytest.mark.parametrize(*add_valid_watcher_data)
def test_add_ticket_watcher(monkeypatch, app, func_name, ticket_key, watcher_name, expected_result, comment):

    def mock_add_ticket_watcher(ticket_key, watcher_name):
        # Since `add_ticket_watcher()` has no return statement, I'm mocking the result as None
        return None

    monkeypatch.setattr(app, "add_ticket_watcher", mock_add_ticket_watcher)

    # Run each input parameter from add_valid_watcher_data to `add_ticket_watcher()`
    watcher = getattr(app, func_name)(ticket_key, watcher_name)

    # If watcher has None value, then `add_ticket_watcher()` execution is successful.
    assert expected_result == watcher


# Negative test case: Setup parameterize test for invalid ticket key
add_invalid_watcher_data = (
    ('func_name', 'ticket_key', 'watcher_name', 'exception_message', 'comment'),
    [
        ('add_ticket_watcher', 'TIC-xx', 'someone', 'Ticket key is empty', 'add watcher at invalid ticket key'),
        ('add_ticket_watcher', None, 'someone', 'Ticket key is empty', 'ticket key has None value'),
    ]
)


@pytest.mark.parametrize(*add_invalid_watcher_data)
def test_exception_add_ticket_watcher(app, func_name, ticket_key, watcher_name, exception_message, comment):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match=exception_message):
      # Run each input parameter from add_invalid_watcher_data to `add_ticket_watcher()`
      getattr(app, func_name)(ticket_key, watcher_name)
```

In `test_add_ticket_watcher()`, I'm not sure what to assert. However, since `App.add_ticket_watcher(ticket_key, watcher_name)` has no return statement. I create a mock function to return `None`.

Is there a better way to achieve the same purpose?

How to create unit test for methods without return statement in Pytest?

Comment: There's no specific answer. Ideally, you would have some way to externally verify that whatever update `add_watcher` is supposed to make was, in fact, made. Failing that, the best you can do is use a mock to verify that it was called using the arguments you expect.

Comment: That test is very hard to understand and I don't think it makes sense. It seems that `ServerInterface` is a wrapper/facade for a `Server`. If `server_interface` is the thing you're testing you should *not* be monkeypatching it. The difficulty with testing this stems from the decision to have `ServerInterface` create its own `Server` instance - read up on *dependency inversion*. If you could inject a mock *server* and check the appropriate interactions with it, that might be more straightforward.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for your response. I updated above code snippet to show what's inside `add_ticket_watcher()`.

From updated code, `add_ticket_watcher()` is adding ticket_key, watcher_name into the database. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by **externally verify**?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thanks for your input. I updated above code snippet and narrowing down the scope to focus more on **Server instance** than **ServerInterface instance**. 

I merged **Server class** to **App class**. `add_ticket_watcher()` behavior is adding ticket_key, watcher_name into the database. I'm not sure what to assert since that function has no return statement. I create a mock function to return `None`.

Comment: Now you aren't testing anything, you're calling the monkey patch.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: You are correct. I just noticed that. Is there a better way to test `add_ticket_watcher()?`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what chepner has mentioned. You can test if logger.info is being called using mock.
And in order to test the negative scenario, you can force it to raise exception using mock side_effects, and then you can test whether logger.exception is getting called.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by forcing negative scenario to raise exception using mock side_effects?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with pytest but unittest. However, I would write these 3 tests for your function ( with a little modification to your existing function :))

Note: Test method names are descriptive, hence, I am not adding extra comments.

app.py

```
from utils import DBConnection
import cx_Oracle

class App:

  def add_ticket_watcher(self, ticket_key, watcher_name):
    if ticket_key is None:
      raise ValueError('Ticket key is empty')

    instance = DBConnection()

    try:
        instance.save(ticket_key, watcher_name)
    except Exception as e:
        raise cx_Oracle.DatabaseError('Database save failed')
```

test_app.py

```
import unittest
import app
import cx_Oracle
from mock import patch

class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.app = app.App()

    def test_if_exception_raised_when_ticket_value_is_none(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            self.app.add_ticket_watcher(None, 'dummyname')

    def test_if_dbconnection_save_is_called(self):
        with patch('app.DBConnection.save') as mock_dbconn_save:
            self.app.add_ticket_watcher(123, 'dummyname')
            self.assertTrue(mock_dbconn_save.called)

    def test_if_dbconnection_save_raises_error(self):
        with patch('app.DBConnection.save', side_effect = Exception) as mock_dbconn_save_exc:
            with self.assertRaises(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError):
                self.app.add_ticket_watcher(123, 'dummyname')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```